# Refresh a partial view in MVC continuously as and when result arrives from multiple methods

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, async-await

I have a specific scenario in which i need to execute multiple methods and at the same time i need to update my view with the result the method returns. To be more specific let's take an example.

Suppose i have 3 Methods named `MethodOne, MethodTwo` and `MethodThree.`

MethodOne returns result: `M1`

MethodTwo returns result: `M2`

MethodThree returns result: `M3`

so in combine my view will display `M1, M2, M3`. I have a way where i can store the result of all the methods at one place but i don't want them to be executed One by One as it might be the case that time difference are more in the completion of each of these methods.

(Currently i am doing 3 ajax call one by one to call these methods).

Is there any way where i can execute all these methods in parallel and what ever method returns the result? first the view gets updated with that result and then other methods continue their execution in the background and as and when other methods gets completed we can refresh the view accordingly.

P.S: I have already done this with jQuery Ajax call as i have mentioned it earlier.

Comment: Have a look at SignalR

Comment: can u please suggest some sample where i can get kickoff ?

Comment: If you showed your existing code it would have been easier, but suggest you look into jQuery/Ajax promises and `$.when()`.